# Math Check - Calculating Output of 819MW Electrical Generator and Transmission at 500kV?

Tags: voltage, power, transformer, math

If a steam turbine generator puts out 819MW at 18,500V (like a unit at Bruce Power Plant), then gets stepped-up for transmission at 500kV, assuming no change in resistance, is the current as follows?

Amperage of electrical generator:

> I = W ÷ V
>
>    = 819MW ÷ 18,500V
>
>    = 44,270A

Step-up to 500kV for transmission assuming no change in R:

> **(18.5kV stepped-up to 500kV is a ratio of ~ 27)**
>
>
>             V(p) x I(p) = V(s) x I(s)
>
>  18.5kV x 44.27kA = 500kV x I(s)
>
>                         I(s) = 18.5kV x 44.27A ÷ 500kV
>
>                               = 1,638A

Am I calculating the amperage correctly with the information given?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. However a real generator would be 3-phase so there would be some \$\sqrt{3}\$'s in the calculation.

Comment: Not knowing what a *change in resistance* is (lossless?), I'd calculate straight from power&secondary voltage: 819 MW / 500 kV.

Comment: Many generators also have a design power factor less than one, meaning that the real power might be 819MW but the generator is designed to operate up to say 850-900MVA, allowing for importing/exporting VARs and harmonics.

Comment: "there would be some \$\sqrt{3}\$'s in the calculation" Specifically you need to divide the current by \$\sqrt{3}\$ to give 946 A in each of the three phase conductors. This assumes the transmission line is operating at unity power factor (a resistive load). If the power factor(PF) is less than 1 you need to divide the current by the PF.